# Get integer on requestbody

Tags: java, spring

Ineed to get the id to delete on the database but I cant get the id parameter this way

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/delete/search/","/delete/search"}, method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Integer deleteUser(@RequestBody Integer id_search) {
        return id_search;
    }
```

I get this error message

```
"message": "JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Integer out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@1b77938; line: 1, column
```

Comment: how are you calling this endpoint?

Comment: this url `http://localhost:8080/seviceRS/delete/search` with this body `{"id_search":2}` on  a delete request

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This statement is wrong

```
@RequestBody Integer id_search
```

This means Spring is expecting a body of type `Integer` class. But what you are passing as the body doesn't match Integer class.

You have many options to fix this.

1. Remove `@RequestBody` and just declare as

   ```
   public Integer deleteUser(Integer id_search) {...}
   ```

   With this you need to call this endpoint as

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/seviceRS/delete/search?id_search=2
   ```
2. You can pass it as `PathVariable` like this

   ```
   http://localhost:8080/seviceRS/delete/search/2
   ```

   For this to work change your controller method like this

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = 
   {"/delete/search/{id_search}"}, method = 
                                          RequestMethod.DELETE)
     @ResponseBody
     public Integer deleteUser(Integer id_search) {...}
   ```
3. If you want to send as body, then you should create a class which matches the json that you are sending.

   For example. Create a class like

   ```
    class Demo {
     private int id_search;
     //Getters & Setters
    }
   ```

   With this approach your controller method looks like

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = {"/delete/search/}, method = 
                     RequestMethod.DELETE)
   @ResponseBody
   public Integer deleteUser(Demo demo) {
        demo.getId_Search();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps you are trying to send a request with JSON text in its body from a Postman client or something similar like this:

```
{
 "id_search":2
}
```

This cannot be deserialized by Jackson since this is not an Integer (it seems to be, but it isn't). An Integer object from java.lang Integer is a little more complex.

For your Postman request to work, simply put (without curly braces `{ }`):

```
2
```