# Can't pass the parameters correctly in java, only String works fine

Tags: java, json

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/pp", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Description getDescription(@RequestBody UserStats stats){
    return new Description(stats.getFirstName() + " " + stats.getLastName() + " hates wacky wabbits");
}

public class UserStats{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    
}
public class Description{
    private String description;

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
   
    public Description(String desc)
    {
        this.description = desc;
    }
}
```

I'm using postman to pass the values in Json

```
{
    "firstName":"a",
    "lastName":"b"
}
```

The result is **HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request**
All code works fine, i'm sure the problem is in @RequestBody or how i pass Json values
If i try to use a simple String instead of UserStats class it's working fine, trying to use Long and passing in json a number it's not working anymore. Same thing with this class.

---

I tried to use POST method instead of GET but same results

Comment: i remember something about explicitly creating a default no-args constructor. try adding one for the UserStats class. and speaking in terms of conventions, when we send a request body we should use POST or PUT, and not GET, even though GET can still pass a request body.

Comment: Using @RequestBody with GET seems unusual, I would not be surprised if Spring would not parse the body of GET.

Comment: In addition to the previous comments, u can use url query param instead of @RequestBody with GET method as it's unconventional, but u still can send request body with GET method though.
Also, please share the code that doesn't work, not the working one.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution that resolve the problem with Long value
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52798549/11500163

Perhaps you are trying to send a request with JSON text in its body from a Postman client or something similar like this:

```
{
 "id_search":2
}
```

This cannot be deserialized by Jackson since this is not an Integer (it seems to be, but it isn't). An Integer object from java.lang Integer is a little more complex.

For your Postman request to work, simply put (without curly braces { }):

```
2
```