# requestbody in Spring-Boot pass a single number using postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Consider this method in backend Spring-Boot project:

```
@PostMapping("/api/do-something")
public ResponseEntity<?> doSomething(@RequestBody Integer num) {
    // ...
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

I want to request to the method using postman with these specification:

> http://localhost:8080/api/do-something

In body section I pass just ***raw 1 (Text)***:

[image]

#### But I get "400 Bad Request Error"

**Why this is happened** and **how can I solve it?**

When I change `@RequestBody Integer num` to `@RequestBody String num` the problem is solved but I don't want to change the method signature.

Comment: What is the content type header sent in the postman request?  What is the content type accepted by the spring boot endpoint?

Comment: raw (Text) in Postman and in spring the default (content-type is not present) @AndrewS

Comment: from what I recall, if not specificed, then spring will use application/json as the default media type.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192783/get-integer-on-requestbody) might help.

Comment: Not true. If the `content-type` in the request is not specified, spring will treat it as `application/octet-stream` to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotate an argument in the controller method with `@RequestBody` will cause it to use a list of registered `HttpMessageConverter` to convert the request body to its value. (see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-requestbody))

A default list of `HttpMessageConverter` are defined and registered at [`WebMvcConfigurationSupport`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/0d10d4beeee3f33f69e4b1d84513e30ea08ccf66/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java#L877) . They have the processing order which the `HttpMessageConverters` has a pretty high priority but it only works for the string argument. That 's why it works if you change the method to `@RequestBody String num`.

To make it works for `@RequestBody Integer num` , you can treat the body as a valid JSON and let Jackson to handle it (BTW An integer is also considered as a valid JSON) . If it detects Jackson in the classpath , it will also register `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` which will try to covert a request body to any Java object.

But `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` only work if the request 's content-type is `application/json` , so you need to make sure the request header is configured with this value.